# TypeScript - Purpose of bin / obj folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Do I need the bin / obj folders for TypeScript project? If so, can you please explain what they are for (for TypeScript) and tell me how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Visual Studio simply uses ASP.NET project structure for TypeScript projects. There is no use for these folders (or for the web.config file) if you are writing pure, client-side TypeScript.

Comment: Absolutely. I delete them too.

Comment: I added the following post-build event to delete them:
`rmdir "$(ProjectDir)bin" /s /q` 
`rmdir "$(ProjectDir)obj" /s /q`
It deletes the obj folder completely, but only empties out the bin folder (I don't know why).